# Relative router path in configuration file in Akka

Tags: java, akka, reactive-programming

I am studying the Akka framework (Java) and building a crawler (which, hopefully, will be open source in the coming months...).
I've create some low-level actors which will be responsible to effectively crawl over data sources and return the found data as a message. This actors are running inside an akka router as I currently can’t make non-blocking calls over my data sources (this solution is suggested in akka documentation).
One of the cool features of the framework is that I can simply configure how the routers works in configuration files, which makes easier to change my system’s behavior. I.e.:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /"*"/querierRouter {
    router = balancing-pool
    nr-of-instances = 50
  }
```

This configuration worked fine in my simpler unit test. The akka system was capable to identify the configuration and associated it to the desired router. However, as my application increased in complexity, different paths from different sizes were created and both of them reach to this router. 
Currently, I’ve paths like this (simplified version):

```
akka://CRAWLER/user/$a/$a/RESOURCE_PROCESSOR/$a/QUERY/querierRouter
```

Which the Akka system is unable to find the correct configuration, sending the following message:

```
akka.ConfigurationException: Configuration missing for router [akka://CRAWLER/user/$a/$a/RESOURCE_PROCESSOR/$a/QUERY/querierRouter] in 'akka.actor.deployment' section.
```

I have searched the documentation but did not found any information about a solution for this. So, my question is: how can I specify a configuration that is valid for ANY path that ends with “querierRouter”? In my mind, this is mandatory to make it viable (as the path can vary dynamically).